# Magento2: caching Rest APIs results

Tags: rest, caching, magento2

I am using the Magento2 REST APIs that don't have any built-in cache, so I have introduced one based on a public module.
Basically what it does is to cache the result of a GET request on products (`GET` requests for paths that match `^\/V1\/products`).

Obviously, details like the stock quantity are not valid anymore if the cache is not invalidated every time someone places an order, but it seems a terrible option.

The only thing I can think of is, based on the website needs, to calculate a good cache TTL (probably X minutes), and accept that the information about stock quantities can be wrong for a short period (X - Y minutes).

Of course a `POST` request to add a product in the cart will always give the correct output (error if out of stock), but there can be some inconsistency with what is shown.

So, my question is: is this a valid approach?
If the answer is no, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled across this today. It may work for you or give you some inspiration (Disclaimer: I've not tried it)

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_APIEnhancer

If you write your own I wouldn't use a ttl. Better would be to use the cache invalidation system and just invalidate the now stale sections. Much more tricky than invalidating the whole cache.

Comment: It's buggy. it causes Magento to instantiate Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver instead of Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver in admin area